# nginx: How to write regex to split URL into host and "everything else"?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

I want to map

```
https://www.example.com/Something/SomethingElse/
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?/Something/SomethingElse/
```

So far I understood that I need the `location` directive in nginx and use the `try_files` inside, something like this:

```
location ~ *???* {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$1;
}
```

Now, the question is: how do I write the regular expression `*???*` to split URL, so I get the `/Something/SomethingElse/` back (into `$1`)? Is it possible?

Perhaps, there is an easier way? nginx variable?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. You may use `request_uri` that contains "everything else" (excluding the host).  Ref: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri .

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but using `$request_uri` results in "rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php"". How do I write it properly?

Comment: `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri`. Please post your full configuration to understand the redirection issue better.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu Can you post this as answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I wasn't available lately. Posted my reply as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable [$request_uri](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) that contains all parts of URL excluding the host (and the scheme - http or https). So, the solution is to use the following code (or something similar)...

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri
}
```

We have a similar variable in Nginx named [$uri](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri). It is not recommended to use it as it can change its value during the run time.